# VMs won't start when I change network from NAT to Bridge adapter

Tags: linux, networking, windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa as host and my guest is Windows 10. When I go over VirtualBox to change the network from NAT to Bridge adapter Windows 10 VM does not start. Screenshots are attached here:

- Network Details

[image: Network Details]

- Changing network from nat to bridge adpater and selecting the network interface

[image: NAT-to-Bridge]

- The error it shows

[image: error]

Things to know about my network

I am in college hostel where the hostel network is 10.2.0.x which is connected to a switch. Gateway is 10.2.0.1. IPs are static. There is also proxy server setup to access the internet which `172.16.0.11:3128`. What is the reason for VM not starting up?

Also all the different network arrangements I can have. If I am able to start up VM then what IPs I should give. I am new to VirtualBox and having more difficulties as my host is Linux.

Comment: Every VM has its own log file. You need to investigate this log file to find clues about the error. // Also, don’t ask multiple questions at once.

Answer (score 1):

It may happen when the configuration file get corrupted for some reason. So: find file VirtualBox.xml-prev (usually located at /home/$user/.VirtualBox/ ); 
then get differences with VirtualBox.xml

```
diff VirtualBox.xml-prev VirtualBox.xml
```

If there are differences on network configuration, restore the previous: delete VirtualBox.xml and change name VirtualBox.xml-prev to VirtualBox.xml

Comment: I think it is rather unlikely the VirtualBox GUI would produce an invalid configuration file.